# Python Matplotlib string-formatting in plots with bold and Italic font

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, fonts

I have a little problem with bold and italic fonts in a plot at the same time.

I tried:

```py
plt.text(0.5,0.5,r'\it{italic} + \bf{bold}' = \it{\bf{both}}')
```

this gives: *italic* and **bold** = **both**

and with:

```py
plt.text(0.5,0.5,r'\it{italic} + \bf{bold}' = \bf{\it{both}}')
```

I get: *italic* and **bold** = *both*

But what I want to get is ***both***

I also tried to use the latex version with `\textbf{...}` and `\textit{...}` and the commands `\mathit{...}` and `\mathbf{...}`.
They work as they should but not if they are used combined. The combination of different "technologies" like `\mathbf{\textbf{...}}` does not help. It is alway only the last style that stays.

I saw a few different questions on that topic but no correct answer, so I hope that asking espacially for this contextless case helps to find an answer. I am looking for a generall solution, not for a workaround for a special case, e.g. using a special font that already looks bold.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Yoi have to use a different font. The work around I mentioned is the answer. If you use:

```
from matplotlib import rc  
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
```

you will get the desired result. The default font in matplotlib seems to not support the bold and italic edits at the same time. Maybe this helps in many other situations you will have with other edits in case you are looking for different combinations.